# Gitlab CI - Publish Failed Test Results to Pages

Tags: gradle, junit, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-pages

I'm creating a simple java project using `Gradle` which generates a test report (i.e. BDD Cucumber, JUnit, etc.). This project is deployed to `Gitlab` where the project is built as part of the `Gitlab CI` process.

My `JUnit` reports are generated in the folder `build/reports/tests/test/` relative to the project path (as an `index.html` and some `CSS` files, etc.).

How do I configure my `.gitlab-ci.yml` to publish the content of `build/reports/tests/test/` to the Gitlab Pages **even after my test cases fail**?

This is what I have in my `.gitlab-ci.yml`: (My repo can be found [HERE](https://gitlab.com/mohammad.mnajar/gitlab-ci-project))

Version 1: Doesn't publish anything to pages

```
image: java:8-jdk

stages:
  - test

before_script:
  - export GRADLE_USER_HOME=`pwd`/.gradle

test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - mkdir public
    - ./gradlew test

  artifacts:
    paths:
      - build/reports/tests/test/
  only:
  - master

after_script:
  - mv build/reports/tests/test/* public
```

---

Version 2: Doesn't execute the `deploy` stage since `test` has failed.

```
image: java:8-jdk

stages:
  - test
  - deploy

before_script:
  - export GRADLE_USER_HOME=`pwd`/.gradle

test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - ./gradlew test

  artifacts:
    paths:
      - build/reports/tests/test/

 pages:
   stage: deploy
   dependencies:
     - test
   script:
   - mkdir public
   - mv build/reports/tests/test/* public
   artifacts:
     paths:
      - public

  only:
  - master
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I solved the issue by adding the `when: always` at the end of my `pages` stage. It now executes the stage regardless of exit code from the dependent stage.

Answer (score 0):

## Just add **when: always** in the artifacts section

```
test:
  stage: test
  allow_failure: true
  image: mcr.microsoft.com/playwright:v1.35.1-focal 

  script:
    - |
      npm install ci
      npm install -D @playwright/test
      npm i -D @playwright/test allure-playwright
      npm install mysql
      npm ci
      npx playwright install --with-deps
      npx playwright install msedge
      npx playwright install chrome
      npx playwright test
      
  timeout: 10 hours #overriding the default gitlab runner timeout optional

  artifacts:
    paths: 
     - ./playwright-report/
     - ./Screenshot/
     - ./Reports/
            
    when: always
    expire_in: 7 days
```